# PyQt4 layout delete all QLabels

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a `toolbar` with right-left controls, and I want to display 2 pages each time the loop ends and then, add them to `self.pdf_layout` and delete the old ones. The point is to step forwards and backwards 2 pages each time.
How can i replace (or delete and reset) the `self.pdf_layout` widgets (QLabels- I use them as image placeholders) ???

```
class pdfViewer(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent,filepath):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    #temp = tempfile.gettempdir()
    #tempfilename=temp+'/unf120.pdf'
    self.filepath = filepath

    # global CurrentPage
    #global currentPage
    self.currentPage = 0

    self.doc = popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.load(self.filepath)
    self.doc.setRenderHint(popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.Antialiasing)
    self.doc.setRenderHint(popplerqt4.Poppler.Document.TextAntialiasing)
    self.scroll_area = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    self.scroll_area.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Dark)
    self.mainlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    #PDF READER CONTROLS
    self.ControlsLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.ControlsWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.ControlsWidget.setLayout(self.ControlsLayout)
    self.pdf_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.pdf_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.pdf_widget.setLayout(self.pdf_layout)
    #toolBar
    self.toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
    #left Button action
    leftAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('left.png'),'Left',self)
    self.toolbar.addAction(leftAction)
    #right Button Action
    rightAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('right.png'),'Right',self)
    #rightRender = self.renderPages(1,currentPage,100)
    self.toolbar.addAction(rightAction)
    rightAction.triggered.connect(self.forwardPages)
    #start Button Action
    startAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('start.png'),'Go to: Start',self)
    self.toolbar.addAction(startAction)
    #end Window Action
    endAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('end.png'),'Go to: end',self)
    self.toolbar.addAction(endAction)
    self.ControlsLayout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    #Zoom Controls 

    # Zoom Label
    zoomLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Zoom: ")
    zoomLabel.setMaximumWidth(50)
    self.ControlsLayout.addWidget(zoomLabel)
    #Zoom ComboBox Widget
    combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
    combo.addItem("50%")
    combo.addItem("60%")
    combo.addItem("70%")
    combo.addItem("80%")
    combo.addItem("90%")
    combo.addItem("100%")
    combo.addItem("120%")
    combo.addItem("150%")
    combo.addItem("170%")
    combo.addItem("200%")
    combo.setMaximumWidth(100)
    self.ControlsLayout.addWidget(combo)


    # add PDF READER Controls to mainlayout
    self.ControlsWidget.setMaximumWidth(300)
    self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.ControlsWidget)


    # by default goes to firstPage of the current document
    self.forwardPages(100)

    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.pdf_widget)
    self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
    self.setLayout(self.mainlayout)
    self.resize(1700,900)
    self.move(500,80)

def firstPage(self,zoomLevel=100):
    self.currentPage = 0

    pdfpage = self.doc.page(self.currentPage)
    image = pdfpage.renderToImage(zoomLevel,zoomLevel)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.label.setScaledContents(True)
    currentWidth = self.scroll_area.frameGeometry().width()-100
    #print currentWidth
    pixScaled = pixmap.scaledToWidth(currentWidth,QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)

    self.label.setPixmap(pixScaled)
    self.pdf_layout.addWidget(self.label)

    print 'set first page'
```

here is the method....

```
def forwardPages(self,zoomLevel=100):

    renderingTime = time.time()
    sum_pages = self.doc.numPages()

    currentPage = self.currentPage  
    for currentPage in range(1):
        print currentPage
        pdfpage = self.doc.page(self.currentPage+1)
        image = pdfpage.renderToImage(zoomLevel,zoomLevel)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        label = QtGui.QLabel()
        label.setScaledContents(True)
        currentWidth = self.scroll_area.frameGeometry().width()-100
        #print currentWidth
        pixScaled = pixmap.scaledToWidth(currentWidth,QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)

        label.setPixmap(pixScaled)
        for i in range(self.pdf_layout.count()): self.pdf_layout.itemAt(i).widget().close()
        self.pdf_layout.addWidget(label)

        print "rendering time = {0}".format(time.time()-renderingTime)  
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.pdf_widget)
    self.currentPage = currentPage
```

Answer (score -1):

You can little bit change your code.

First you store current pages like this

```
currentLeftPage = self.currentLeftPage
currentRightPage = self.currentRightPage
```

And you change the pdfpage like

```
pdfLeftPage = self.doc.page(self.currentLeftPage+2)
pdfRightPage = self.doc.page(self.currentRightPage+2)
```

then you renderd `leftImage` and `rightImage` separatly.

Note: You may modify or optimize the above thing.

Comment: Ok.thnx 4 that. That's the half part. The second part is how can i delete the previous two and set the new ?

Comment: Can you try this `widget.setParent(None)`

Comment: yeap. I did it. Nothing. Take a look here http://imgur.com/DyOTbbr 
That's the next 2 pages